# Call a function, myfunction, from a JavaScript file only after that file is executed in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript files. The first file, a.js, checks the screen size and loads file b.js if the screen size is less than 600 pixels. After the condition satisfies, I am calling a constructor function that is defined in file b.js. But it is giving me reference error that the function is not defined.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
    const MinPx = 600;

    function downloadJS() {
      var x = document.createElement('script');
      x.type = 'text/javascript';
      x.src = '/js/b.js';
      document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
    if (jQuery(document).width() > MinPx) {
      downloadJS();
      new tpc("Homepage", jQuery("#a"));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The file `b.js` is not loaded yet. You need to place the constructor-calling code in the load callback.

Comment: but how do I do that?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
   
   const MinPx= 600;

   function downloadJS(){
     var x=document.createElement('script');
     x.type='text/javascript';
     x.src='/js/b.js';
     document.body.appendChild(x);
     } 

   if (jQuery(document).width() > MinPx){

    downloadJS();   
                        new tpc("Homepage", jQuery("#a"));
        
   }
  
    });
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: you just need to add `x.onload = function(){<code to execute after load>}` before the `document.body.appendChild(x)` line.